# call rss inside my application for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

OK I have application with buttons on start screen. On few buttons I want to connect RSS feed directly to show.

Can somebody give me a clue how to start with it.

I am pretty new to iOS so be kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the wonderful world of iOS development :) There's a great tutorial that should teach you exactly what you need: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

Cheers,

Johannes

Comment: ok as I understood I write this classes into my application and not start new one. Then on the place for action invoked with pressing button I call RootViewController and it should show me content??? Am I right? By the way thx for link

Comment: Hi Akosha, you need to first understand the basics of iOS development. This is a good place to start: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1 Cheers!

Comment: Yes I know trying to keep track with learning and demand to act fast... Will be much better in few months... I manage to implement it in code :) Cheers